# Is it possible to reposition anchor points with the arrow keys when drawing with the pen tool without stopping the line?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

When drawing with the pen tool in Photoshop it is possible to adjust the last placed anchor point with the arrow keys and then continue drawing the same line.  In illustrator, if you do the same thing the line stops and you have to restart the line.

Is there an option in illustrator to continue drawing after using the arrow keys?

I know that if you hold down the spacebar you can adjust the point before letting go of the mouse/pen, but I prefer the control that the arrow keys give.

Comment: HI and welcome this site does not work well for asnwers that are basically: "No." Since thats less than minimum required text. Its possible to program your own pen tool though

Answer (score 0):

After moving the point using the arrows, instead of continuing from the next point, click on the last point and continue. If it's a curve point, drag following the curve direction before creating the next point.

[image: Path]

Comment: Yes, that's what I've started doing. I just need to get into the habit of clicking back on the last point..still it would be nice to have the option.

Comment: @Danielillo, what screen cap software are you using? Your responses are always great. -thx.

Comment: @13ruce Kap.........................

Answer (score 0):

## No

What you want is not possible in Illustrator.

As soon as a user taps an arrow key, the currently active anchor point is no longer seen as "active" for continuation. You *must* click (or click-drag) the anchor again with the Pen Tool to continue drawing from it.

Holding the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and mouse button down, at the same time, will let you drag the mouse to reposition an anchor *and* keep it active for continuation. This the only way to keep the anchor active for continuation while moving it.